# Why am I getting two different 'formats' of hex in my bytes while evaluating an HMAC?

Tags: c#, encoding, hex, base64, hmac

I'm getting a signed payload from an authentication source that comes in a base64 encoded and URL encoded format. I'm getting confused somewhere while evaluating, and ending up with similar data in different 'formats'.

Here's my code:

```
//Split the message to payload and signature
string[] split = raw_message.Split('.');

//Payload
string base64_payload = WebUtility.UrlDecode(split[0]);
byte[] payload = Convert.FromBase64String(base64_payload);

//Expected signature
string base64_expected_sig = WebUtility.UrlDecode(split[1]);
byte[] expected_sig = Convert.FromBase64String(base64_expected_sig);

//Signature
byte[] signature = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(payload);

//Output as a string
var foo = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(expected_sig);
var bar = BitConverter.ToString(signature);
```

The expected signature (`foo`) comes out like so:
`76eba09fcb54877299dcbd1e1e35717e3bd42e066e7ecdb131c7d0161dec3418`

The computed signature (`bar`) is as follows:

```
76-EB-A0-9F-CB-54-87-72-99-DC-BD-1E-1E-35-71-7E-3B-D4-2E-06-6E-7E-CD-B1-31-C7-D0-16-1D-EC-34-18
```

Obviously, when comparing bytes for bytes, this doesn't work.

I see that I'm having to convert the `expected_sig` and the `signature` in different ways to get them to display as a string, but I can't figure out *how* I need to change the expected signature to get to where I can compare bytes for bytes.

I can obviously work around the issue but simply converting the string `bar`, but that's dirty and I just don't like it.

Where am I going wrong here? What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good news is that the hash computation appears to be working.

The bad news is that you're receiving the hash in a brain-dead fashion. For some reason it seems that the authors decided it was a good idea to:

- Compute the hash (fine)
- Convert this binary data to text as hex (fine)
- Convert the hex back into binary data by applying ASCII/UTF-8/anything-ASCII-compatible encoding (why?)
- Convert the result back into text using base64 (what?)
- URL-encode the result (which wouldn't even be necessary with hex...)

Using *either* base64 *or* hex on the original binary makes sense, but applying *both* is crazy.

Anyway, it's fairly easy for you to do the same thing. For example:

```
string hexSignature = string.Join("", signature.Select(b => b.ToString("x2")));
byte[] hexSignatureUtf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hexSignature);
string finalSignature = Convert.ToBase64String(hexSignatureUtf8);
```

That should now match `WebUtility.UrlDecode(split[1])`.

Alternatively, you can work backwards from what's in the result, but I wouldn't go as far as parsing the hex back to bytes - it would be simpler to keep the first line of the above, but use:

```
string expectedHexBase64 = WebUtility.UrlDecode(split[1]);
byte[] expectedHexUtf8 = Convert.FromBase64String(expectedHexBase64);
string expectedHex = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(expectedHexUtf8);
```

Then compare it with `hexSignature`.

Ideally, you should talk to whoever's providing you with the crazy format and hit them with a cluestick though...